# Text resizing depending on the amount of copy

Tags: html, ios, css

I have a strange behaviour with a piece of code that I'm currently working on within a media query. 
I have used the same div class to style a piece of text that appears across various pages within the site, but the text is appearing different sizes depending on whether there is 1, or 2 or more lines of text.

The div class in question is `.credits_mobile`

HTML

```
<div id="project_content_mobile">
<div class="project_title_mobile">
Spaces
</div>
<div class="project_description_mobile">
A fashion editorial based around the quote ‘There is no difference between time and any of the three dimensions of space except that our consciousness moves along it’ H.G.Wells The Time Machine (p.374,2001.) Through the use of mirrors and reflections the aim was to create new spaces and perspectives that play with what the eye sees and takes influence from the cubist movement. 
    </div>
<div class="credits_mobile">
MUA: Meg Purnell<br> 
Models: Yasmin Minto, Lenka Slípková
</div>
<img src="images/projects/spaces/1_mobile.jpg"/>
<img src="images/projects/spaces/2_mobile.jpg"/>
<img src="images/projects/spaces/3_mobile.jpg"/>
<img src="images/projects/spaces/4_mobile.jpg"/>
<img src="images/projects/spaces/5_mobile.jpg"/>
<img src="images/projects/spaces/6_mobile.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Linked CSS file 1 - Layout

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {
body {    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    height: 100%;
}

#homepage_portrait_image{
    position:absolute;
    width: 76%;
    height: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: -100;
}

#homepage_portrait_image img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: -100;
}

/***********
Nav
************/

#nav_top_background{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_top_content{
    position:fixed;
    top: 2.5%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 45%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_top_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav_bottom_background{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_bottom_content{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 2.5%;
    right: 3%;
    width: 25.5%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_bottom_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav_left_background{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_left_content{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 2.5%;
    left: 3%;
    width: 6%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_left_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav_right_background{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_right_content{
    position:fixed;
    top: 2.5%;
    right: 3%;
    width: 6%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_right_content img{
    width: 100%;
}


/***********
Work
************/

#mobile_image_grid{
    visibility: visible;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 76%; 
}

#mobile_image_grid img{
    width: 100%;    
}

.project_title_work_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 6%;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/********** Hidden ************/
#image_grid,
#image_content,
#video_content,
#typographic_content,
#nav_left_background,
#nav_right_background,
#mobile_image_grid_landscape{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
/********** Hidden ************/



/***********
About, Contact, & Project Intros
************/

#typographic_content_mobile{
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 76%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

/***********
Project
************/

#project_content_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 12%;
    left: 12%;
    width: 76%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: -100;
}

#project_content_mobile img{
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    z-index: -100;
}


.project_title_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: -100;
}

.project_description_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: -100;
}

.credits_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: -100;
}

video{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;  
}

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
body {    
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
    height: 100%;
}

#homepage_portrait_image{
    position:absolute;
    width: 76%;
    height: 80%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: -100;
}

#homepage_portrait_image img{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    z-index: -100;
}

/***********
Nav
************/

#nav_top_background{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_top_content{
    position:fixed;
    top: 3%;
    left: 1.5%;
    width: 27%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_top_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav_bottom_background{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 11%;
    background-color: #fff;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_bottom_content{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 3%;
    right: 1.5%;
    width: 16.2%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_bottom_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav_left_background{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_left_content{
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 3%;
    left: 1.5%;
    width: 3.6%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_left_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

#nav_right_background{
    position:fixed;
    top: 0%;
    right: 0%;
    width: 12%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}

#nav_right_content{
    position:fixed;
    top: 3%;
    right: 1.5%;
    width: 3.6%;
    z-index: 200;
}

#nav_right_content img{
    width: 100%;
}

/***********
Work
************/

#mobile_image_grid_landscape { 
    visibility: visible;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11%;
    left: 18.125%;
    width: 63.75%;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

#mobile_image_grid_landscape img{
    position:relative;
    width:49%; 
    display:inline-block;
}

.project_title_work_mobile {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width:50%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/********** Hidden ************/
#image_grid,
#image_content,
#video_content,
#typographic_content,
#nav_left_background,
#nav_right_background,
#mobile_image_grid,
project_content_mobile{
    visibility: hidden;
    display: none;
}
/********** Hidden ************/

/***********
About, Contact, & Project Intros
************/

#typographic_content_mobile{
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 63.75%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 0;
}

/***********
Project
************/

#project_content_mobile{
    visibility:visible;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 11%;
    left: 18.125%;
    width: 63.75%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: -100;
}

    .project_content_mobile img{
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    display:block;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
    }

    .project_title_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: -100;
    }

    .project_description_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    z-index: -100;
    }

    .credits_mobile{
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    z-index: -100;
    }

    video{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;  
    }
```

Linked CSS file 2 - Typography

```
/* ----------- iPhone 6 ----------- */

/* Portrait and Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 

}

/* Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: portrait) {

/***********
Work
************/

.project_title_work_mobile,
.project_title_work_mobile a:link,
.project_title_work_mobile a:visited,
.project_title_work_mobile a:hover,
.project_title_work_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:40px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/***********
Project
************/

.project_title_mobile,
.project_title_mobile a:link,
.project_title_mobile a:visited,
.project_title_mobile a:hover,
.project_title_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:90px;
    line-height: 90px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: -5px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;    
}

.project_description_mobile,
.project_description_mobile a:link,
.project_description_mobile a:visited,
.project_description_mobile a:hover,
.project_description_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;    
}

.credits_mobile{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:25px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

}

/* Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 375px) 
  and (max-device-width: 667px) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
  and (orientation: landscape) {
  /***********
Work
************/

.project_title_work_mobile,
.project_title_work_mobile a:link,
.project_title_work_mobile a:visited,
.project_title_work_mobile a:hover,
.project_title_work_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:700;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #000000;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/***********
Project
************/

.project_title_mobile,
.project_title_mobile a:link,
.project_title_mobile a:visited,
.project_title_mobile a:hover,
.project_title_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: -5px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;    
}

.project_description_mobile,
.project_description_mobile a:link,
.project_description_mobile a:visited,
.project_description_mobile a:hover,
.project_description_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;    
}

.credits_mobile,
.credits_mobile a:link,
.credits_mobile a:visited,
.credits_mobile a:hover,
.credits_mobile a:active{
    font-family: 'Avenir-Book';
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
}
```

Below are some comparison images showing how the text is currently appearing.

Portrait Orientation

[image]

[image]

Landscape Orientation

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this css properties

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```